# XMLのデータをXSLで取得したい

Tags: xsl, xpath

初めまして。質問させて頂きます。
XML+XSLTでプログラミング中です。

次のようなXMLがあるとします。

```
<DATA>
    <F1>あ</F1>
    <F2>い</F2>
    <F3>う</F3>
    <F4>え</F4>
    <F5>お</F5>
    <F1>か</F1>
    <F2>き</F2>
    <F3>く</F3>
    <F4>け</F4>
    <F5>こ</F5>
    <F1>さ</F1>
    <F2>し</F2>
    <F3>す</F3>
    <F4>せ</F4>
    <F5>そ</F5>
</DATA>
```

この中で、`F1='か'`の下の`F3`のデータ(この場合は`く`)のみを取得するxpathの書き方が解らず悩んでおります。
どなたかお分かりになる方が居られましたら、ご教示お願いできますでしょうか？
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

もし@user20662さんがWindows + MSXMLのようなXPath 1.0の世界でこの質問をされておられるようでしたら、@pghoさんの回答でもよいと思われます．しかし世の中はすでにXPath 3.0まで進んでいるので、やはり最低でもXPath 2.0ではどうなるか？は知っておいて損はないでしょう．

@sayuriさんの御指摘のように、`//F1[text()='か']/following-sibling::F3/text()`をXPath 2.0で使用すると以下の様に２つのテキストノードが選択されてしまいます．（oXygen 18.1で試しています）従って使用するXpathのバージョンが上がっても確実に動作するようにしておくには、`//F1[text()='か']/following-sibling::F3[1]/text()`のように書いておくのが確実です．

[image: Xpath 2.0での実行結果]

もしXpath 2.0以上を使用するならば、`string(/DATA/F1[string(.) eq 'か']/following-sibling::F3[1])`くらいが適当ではないでしょうか？

- "く"を取得するのはtext()を返すよりxs:stringを返す方が適切と思います．（実際XPath 2.0を使用するXSLTスタイルシートでas="text()"のように使うことはまずないからです．
- シーケンスを比較する一般比較演算子"="でなく、文字列比較を明示して値比較演算子"eq"を使用します．

結果は次のように"く"が値として返るようになります．

[image: Xpath 2.0での記述]

以上 御参考になれば

Answer (score 0):

考え方としては

1. `//F1` : すべての`F1`要素
2. `[text()='か']` : …のうちテキストが`か`であるもの
3. `/following-sibling::F3` : …と同階層で後ろにあるすべての`F3`要素
4. `/text()` : …のテキスト

を繋げて以下のようになります。

```
//F1[text()='か']/following-sibling::F3/text()
```

Comment: `く`だけでなく`す`もヒットしてしまうので、`[1]`で制限しないといけないかと。

Comment: @sayuri XSL関数のノードの文字列化では基本的に先頭のノードしか使用しないので省略しています